# Technology Choice for Tablet Solution with Offline Capabilities handling Personal Information

Tags: android, ios, html, tablet

We are looking to rewrite a form-based application with a fairly tight time-scale (ideally, we would be launching the beta mid-July, and the final version by September). The current platform is showing its limitations and would require an exorbitant amount to bring into line with our requirements. As such, we are looking to bring the technology in-house, and writing our own solution.

Requirements:

- **Must be able to handle loss of network connectivity - the user may not always have internet access**
- **Must have secure two-way communication with the server - the information being uploaded and downloaded can contain personal information, and it is imperative that we not be responsible for data-loss**
- **Must be able to synchronise and update / remove records already on the tablet - the information can change, and the user must have access to information as "fresh" as possible**
- **Must be able to store a large number of records (~1000+ records, a few kB each, so total 5+ MB) offline - depending on the tablet model, the user may only have internet access via wifi at the beginning and end of a day, so as many records as might be accessed should be downloaded and stored**
- Should be accessible on both iOS and Android

The solution we have currently is a form app, which fails heavily on point three, which is rapidly becoming a deal-breaker. The solutions that have been floated are:

- An HTML5 website with offline capabilities, through the tablet's web browser
- A website wrapped in an off-the-shelf app "shell" to provide offline capabilities, deployed through the app stores
- A custom-built app (through Xamarin or similar) to be deployed through the app stores

Unfortunately, we are a company of desktop developers - we have no in-house experience with tablet applications currently. That being said, the application is tied very closely with several of our other products, so it would be difficult to outsource the development.

The question, therefore, is this:

**As a mobile application developer, what approach would be "recommended" to build an offline-capable app that must communicate securely with a server when it can?**

Comment: What you mean with "a large number of records"? 5mb or 5gb?

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs probably breaking the 5 MB mark - possibly significantly more if we include images of personal identifiers (e.g. passports) that we would want to keep encrypted - I have edited the minimum into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for 5 mb of data that needed to be synchronized, I would build an web service from where you can get the data for your mobile application.

I prefer JSON Format for the data.

When your app logs in while internet connection, the app can fetch the complete data from the web service.

What I do then, is to compress or archive the json as file to the app internal filesystem.

Now there are only two scenarios for the app:

offline (login):

- get the archived json file and do what you want with your data

online (login)

- fetch the data again from the web service, archive it and then do what you want with your data

To synchronize the data back to the backend is not really mobile application stuff. You have to think about your architecture in the backend.

For security ensure you have ssl enabled for the connection to the web service.

I am native iOS developer but I build something similar with Symfony as Backend and three native applications (iOS, Android and Windows)

You could also use firebase as a backend, it really depends on your needs.

At the end, im just a stranger from the internet :) and normally when a customer needs an estimation, we really need time for such an estimation and to choose the right platforms that fits for the customer.

Comment: We're already pretty familiar with JSON for communication, so that's definitely a plus - in terms of the architecture for the client-side, would this be better realised as an offline capable web-page, or would the storage requirement push this more towards a custom app to be deployed through the app stores?

Comment: How much time you have to finish the apps?

Comment: That's part of the "conversation" with management - ideally, we want to go from scratch to a fully operating and tested system by September (and we're willing to bring in contractors to get us most of the way there) - the worry is that the app store turnaround will be a pretty hefty overhead, especially if we want to do quick fixes in-the-field, so to speak

Comment: Yes this is correct, normally companies will use some continuous integration to handle the stores overhead. But from what you say, that you are most desktop developers I would recommend something like phonegap. Hybrid would be the best choice for you, concerning the time and the men power.